# Restrict Access to a Servlet by Port

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, servlet-filters

My Tomcat server have one service with three connectors listening to ports 8080, 8081 and 50000 and I would like to allow access to a few servlets only from port 50000.

I tried to filter the client's access by port using `RemoteHostFilter` and `RemoteIPFilter` but I didn't work.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>RemoteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>deny</param-name>
        <param-value>\d+\.\d+\.\d+.\d+:8080</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>RemoteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/my-servlet-mapping</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I also tried to achive this using `<Context>` and `<Valve>` but it didn't work either.

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javadoc of [`RemoteAddrFilter`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/filters/RemoteAddrFilter.html):

> Concrete implementation of `RequestFilter` that filters based on the string representation of the **remote client's IP address**.

Not the server's IP address, but the *client's* IP address.

To filter on server port, write your own filter implementation.